# Proving the equation of the Tangent Plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you go about proving the equation of the tangent plane
$$z = f_x(x_0,y_0) \cdot (x-x_0) + f_y (x_0,y_0) \cdot (y-y_0)$$

for someone who is on pre-Calculus, but have been introduced to vectors in 2d, functions of two variables, gradients.

Anyone with a good proof?

Comment: Take a cross-section parallel to the $xz$ plane and show the line and curve are tangent there, then do the same thing with a cross-section parallel to the $yz$ plane?

Comment: How are we supposed to show that a formula involving partial derivatives is correct without referencing some calculus?